# Asp.net Core application on live server is throwing exception to a directory that is in another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

I have an asp.net core 2.2 web application that is using cookies based authentication to allows users to view static html files if they are signed in. This works on a testing server, but when put onto live IIS the application throws an exception saying the directory of the static files is not found. However, the directory not found is pointing to another application which is why I'm confused. This is based off of Scott Allen's tutorial for static file middleware: https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/10/06/authorization-policies-and-middleware-in-asp-net-5.aspx

There is also a known bug with asp.net core 2.2 and in-process hosting:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4206

An additional CurrentDirectoryHelper class was needed.

I have tried restarting the application pool in IIS. That solves the problem temporarily, however the next day the exception is thrown again.

**Startup.cs**

```
  public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services.AddAuthentication( options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {

                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Index";
                    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            });
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Authenticated", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser());
            });

            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                //options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                // Make the session cookie essential
                //options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {


            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseProtectFolder(new ProtectFolderOptions
            {
                Path = "/StaticFiles",
                PolicyName = "Authenticated",

            });



                app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "StaticFiles")),
                RequestPath = "/StaticFiles",
                OnPrepareResponse = context =>
                {
                    context.Context.Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store";
                    context.Context.Response.Headers["Expires"] = "-1";
                    context.Context.Response.Headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
                }
            });




            app.UseCookiePolicy();



            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            });
        }

        private object RedirectResult()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**ProtectFolder.cs**

```
   public class ProtectFolderOptions
    {
        public PathString Path { get; set; }
        public string PolicyName { get; set; }
    }
    // Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
    public static class ProtectFolderExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseProtectFolder(this IApplicationBuilder builder, ProtectFolderOptions options)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<ProtectFolder>(options);
        }
    }

    // You may need to install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions package into your project
    public class ProtectFolder
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly PathString _path;
        private readonly string _policyName;

        public ProtectFolder(RequestDelegate next,ProtectFolderOptions options)
        {
            _next = next;
            _path = options.Path;
            _policyName = options.PolicyName;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
        {



            if (httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(_path))
            {
                //var authorized = await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(httpContext.User, null, _policyName);

                bool authenticated = string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpContext.Session.GetString("Username"));
                if (authenticated == true)
                {
                    await httpContext.ChallengeAsync();
                    return;
                }
            }



            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }
```

**CurrentDirectoryHelper.cs**

```
 internal class CurrentDirectoryHelpers
    {
        internal const string AspNetCoreModuleDll = "aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll";

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport(AspNetCoreModuleDll)]
        private static extern int http_get_application_properties(ref IISConfigurationData iiConfigData);

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct IISConfigurationData
        {
            public IntPtr pNativeApplication;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.BStr)]
            public string pwzFullApplicationPath;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.BStr)]
            public string pwzVirtualApplicationPath;
            public bool fWindowsAuthEnabled;
            public bool fBasicAuthEnabled;
            public bool fAnonymousAuthEnable;
        }

        public static void SetCurrentDirectory()
        {
            try
            {
                // Check if physical path was provided by ANCM
                var sitePhysicalPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_IIS_PHYSICAL_PATH");
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sitePhysicalPath))
                {
                    // Skip if not running ANCM InProcess
                    if (GetModuleHandle(AspNetCoreModuleDll) == IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    IISConfigurationData configurationData = default(IISConfigurationData);
                    if (http_get_application_properties(ref configurationData) != 0)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    sitePhysicalPath = configurationData.pwzFullApplicationPath;
                }

                Environment.CurrentDirectory = sitePhysicalPath;
            }
            catch
            {
                // ignore
            }
        }
    }
```

**Program.cs**

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // bug in asp.net core 2.2 where application can't find static files, this is the official temporary fix until next version of asp.net core
            CurrentDirectoryHelpers.SetCurrentDirectory(); 
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
            .UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")
            //.UseKestrel()
            //.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            //.UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseIIS()
            ;


    }
```

**Web.config**

The modules attribute was originally "AspNetCoreModuleV2" but was changed to "AspNetCoreModule" due to a 500.0 In-Process Handler Load Failure

```
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
```

The exception that is thrown is as follows:

**Internal Server Error**

An error occurred while starting the application.
DirectoryNotFoundException: C:\inetpub\NetCoreSites\AnotherApplication\StaticFiles\
Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(string root, ExclusionFilters filters)

DirectoryNotFoundException: C:\inetpub\NetCoreSites\AnotherApplication\StaticFiles\

**Raw Exception Details**
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: C:\inetpub\NetCoreSites\AnotherApplication\StaticFiles\
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
   at ActualApplication.Web.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) in C:\Users\someuser\source\repos\ActualApplication\ActualApplication.Web\Startup.cs:line 126
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

The "AnotherApplication" is just an alias for another one of our applications. The "ActualApplication" is the alias for the real one. I'm confused with how the directory cannot be found in "AnotherApplication" when the directory with the actual static files is actually in "ActualApplication".

The exception shows that it occurs in line 126 of the Startup.cs file ,but that is just declaring the "newStaticFileOptions" for the static file directory I wanted to add.

Comment: Could you please post the folder architecture for your "ActualApplication" and "AnotherApplication" and the relationship between these two application?

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding. If you mean the projects themselves, the "Actual Application" is just an console application(asp.net core web) with a C# library for authentication. The "StaticFiles" directory is on the same level as the wwwroot folder. The "Another Application" has a C# library for the database, a console application(asp.net core web) , and a C# library for authentication. The only relationship is that they are on the same server in IIS and development. However they both have their own separate sites. Do you mean the folder architecture after publishing? @BrandoZhang